# Word COM in scheduled task on Windows Server

Tags: windows, ms-word, automation, windows-server-2008, server

I have an application that uses COM to automate Word. It needs to run even when a user is not logged in. I achieved this on Windows 7 by making it run as a scheduled task which runs at startup and doesn't require a user to be logged on. I also had to use the 'hack' where you add a 'Desktop' folder in 'C:/Windows/SysWow64/config/systemprofile'.

I tried this same method in Windows Server 2012, but it doesn't work. I can see in the task scheduler that the application is starting an instance of Word. However, it then appears to 'hang' and nothing happens. I think perhaps the invisible instance of Word is showing an error message which causes the whole thing to hang, as I cannot dismiss the message.

Has anyone else had trouble getting COM to work on windows server? Is there any way of showing hidden instances of Word to see if an error dialog is showing? Or any other way of diagnosing what the problem is?

I know ideally we would have an app that created the word documents without using COM, but this is not an option at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Does your app work when run as a logged-in user?

In the past I've run into what sound like similar problems, when running programs that try to use COM interfaces; some tasks work, but others simply don't function unless run as a logged-in user with an interactive desktop.

For me the simplest solution was to set up the machine to log in as a user at boot (which you can set up in the control panel - or I think there might also be a sysinternals tool that supports configuring that nowadays), then make sure that task scheduler/Jenkins/whatever you use launches the app as the logged-in user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try this. Are there any security implications regarding having a user automatically logged on?

Comment: As long as remote access to the machine (e.g. remote desktop or services you use to launch processes remotely) is sufficiently protected, and the machine is headless (or otherwise has no physical access to the console), I'm not aware of any security implications. I suppose one thing to consider is to make sure background apps that launch when the user logs in (like software updaters) don't do anything to change the system when you're not expecting it.